# Angular service with parameters error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to  send two variables from angular service to mvc controller. And I am getting errors all the time. Now I am getting the error that compName doesn't exist. I have been stacked for a few hour, I tried to debug it with the angular debugger but no luck so far.
I think that my error has something to do with the angular controller is trying to call the service on load instead on click, but I don't know how to fix that.

```
        myApp.service('getDocTypesService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
        var allSettings = null;
        this.getDocTypes = function (compName, custName) {
            var def = $q.defer()
            if (allSettings) {
                def.resolve(allSettings);
            } else {
                $http.post('GetDocTypes', { companyName: compName, customerName: custName })
                  .then(function (response) {
                      var response = $.parseJSON(response.data)
                      allSettings = response;
                      def.resolve(allSettings);
                  });
            }
            return def.promise;
        }
        }]);
```

This is my angular controller and the service:

```
      myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'getDocTypesService',
      function ($scope, getDocTypesService) {
      $scope.docSettings = '';
          getDocTypesService.getDocTypes(compName, custName).then(function (value) {
          $scope.docSettings = value

          })

          };
      }
      ]);
```

This is the HTML:
    
    `<select ng-model = "selectedDocument" ng-click="getDocTypes(selectedCompany, enteredCustomer)">
    <option>Select document</option>
    <option ng-repeat="docSetting in docSettings" value=" {{docSetting.Doc_Type}}">{{docSetting.Doc_Type}}</option>
    </select>`

Comment: Hi there, you should tell us what errors you are getting...

Comment: if you want call getDocTypes function on click, you must define the function in the controller's scope. 
$scope.getTypes= function (..){...};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

controller:

```
$scope.getTypes = function(comp, cust) {
    getDocTypesService.getDocTypes(comp, cust).then(function (value) {
          $scope.docSettings = value
    });
};
```

Template:

```
<select ng-model = "selectedDocument" ng-click="getTypes(selectedCompany, enteredCustomer)">
```

Obs: selectedCompany and enteredCustomer must be $scope variables defined before the click happens.

Answer (score 0):

.factory('MagComments', function ($resource) {
return $resource('http://localhost/dooleystand/ci/api/magCommenct/:id', {
loginID : organEntity,
password : organCommpassword,
id : '@magId'
});
})

Answer (score 0):

you did pass parameter throw function that doesn't exixt.
you need to define

```
$scope.getDocTypes = function(selectedCompany, enteredCustomer){
getDocTypesService.getDocTypes(selectedCompany, enteredCustomer).then(function (value) {
          $scope.docSettings = value

          })
}
```